# Get a json output in node.js (Using elasticsearch and express as a web framework )

Tags: json, node.js, express, elasticsearch

I am using node.js to build a search engine web app on top of elasticsearch. I have indexed a website in my elasticsearch using sense and now using my index in express to build a webpage.

This is my javascript:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var client = elasticsearch.Client({
  hosts: [
    'localhost:9200'
  ]
});

module.exports.search = function(searchData, callback) {
  client.search({
    index: 'demoindex1',
    type: 'SearchTech',
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: {
            match: {
              "newContent": searchData.searchTerm
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }).then(function (resp) {
    callback(resp.hits.hits);
  }, function (err) {
      callback(err.message)
      console.log(err.message);
  });
}
```

This is my routes javascript:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var searchModule = require('../search_module/search.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/search-results', function(req, res) {
  searchModule.search(req.body, function(data) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', results: data });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my ejs file which I'm using to create web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <form action='/search-results' method='post'>
      <input type="text" name="searchTerm" placeholder="your search term here">
      <button type="submit"> SEARCH </button>
    </form>
    <ul>
      <% if(locals.results) { %>
        <% results.forEach( function( result ) { %>
          <li>
            <%= result._source.title %>
            <br><%= result._source.U %>
          </li>
        <% }) %>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The webpage I am getting looks this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8dVE.png

If I am searching for a query, I am getting a title of the query that I searched for. But it is not in json form. I would like my web page to print the same result(JSON form) that we get in elasticsearch if we do a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to displaying the `results` as `json data` is by using [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) in the `ejs` template

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>hello</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <form action='/search-results' method='post'>
      <input type="text" name="searchTerm" placeholder="your search term here">
      <button type="submit"> SEARCH </button>
    </form>
      <% if(locals.results) { %>
        <pre>
           <%- JSON.stringify(results,null,2) %>
        </pre>
      <% } %> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @keety Thanks. Now I am getting JSON output of elasticsearch.

Comment: @Val that is not a typo `<%-` is used to display  [unescaped html](http://ejs.co/)

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad (rusty me!), thanks for correcting.